# Word VBA Array not behaving as expected

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I'm iterating through a list of keywords to define terms in a document but only certain keywords will get picked up.

For instance, with Array("Agreement", "deed", "AGREEMENT", "letter agreement", "letter", "Undertaking"), "Agreement" and "letter" get picked up just fine, but letter agreement and Undertaking do not.

I've tried rearranging the order of the array but that does nothing.

I'm guessing there's something fundamental about arrays I'm misunderstanding. I'm more familiar with python and am going for list functionality.

Full code is below. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

```
    Function getagree() As String

    Dim aggrlist As Variant
    aggrlist = Array("Agreement", "NDA", "deed", "AGREEMENT", "letter                         
    agreement", "letter", "Undertaking", "Confidentiality Undertaking",         
    "agreement")

    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    With myRange.Find
        For Each aggr In aggrlist
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = aggr
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .Execute Forward:=True
            If .Found = True Then
                getagree = aggr
            End If
        Next
    End With

    End Function
```

Comment: it looks like you are breaking to a new line in the middle of a string, which i'm guessing is causing the problem.

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module will help pick up these sorts of problems moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an underscore (_) to break your string into multiple lines...

```
aggrlist = Array("Agreement", "NDA", "deed", "AGREEMENT", _
                    "letter agreement", "letter", "Undertaking", _
                        "Confidentiality Undertaking", "agreement")
```